# Node.js deployment in and Amazon server instance with flightplan

Tags: node.js, deployment, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I need to make a deployment of a node.js application with flightplan.js in an Amazon server that needs an .pem key file to do the login.
Normally i'd log into my ssh terminal like this:

```
:~$ ssh -i key_file.pem ubuntu@amazon_server_instance_ip
```

But now i need to do this with flightplan and i don't know what to put in my target that normally it goes like this:

```
plan.target('testing', {
    host: 'amazon_server_instance_ip',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password','
    agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
    repository: 'http://github.com/my_user/my_repo.git',
    branch: 'master',
    maxDeploys: 10
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, just like this:

```
plan.target('testing', {
    host: 'amazon_server_instance_ip',
    username: 'username',
    agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
    repository: 'http://github.com/my_user/my_repo.git',
    branch: 'master',
    privateKey: '/path/to/private/key.pem',
    maxDeploys: 10
});
```

Thanks to @mscdex.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions here:

1. Use your existing configuration and add your `key_file.pem` to your ssh agent via `ssh-add` before running your script.
2. Change your configuration to use `privateKey: '/path/to/key_file.pem'` instead of `agent: ....`.

Comment: Did the second one, but leave the `agent` field (it was necessary), and erase the `password` field (is not needed).